# How to put measures on x-axis with date and time combine in python using tkinter and matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a small GUI application using tkinter, matplotlib and numpy. Here user will upload an excel file and get multi line graph. But the main problem is I couldn't put the measures on x-axis. Here date and time combination will be the measure of x-axis. But only year is coming as measure. Here I am sharing my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Data Analyser')
label1.config(font=('Arial', 20))
canvas1.create_window(400, 50, window=label1)

def getExcel1 ():
      global df

      import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
      df = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
      daytime=df.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['Day'],r['Time']),1)
      global bar1
      x = daytime
      y1 = df['Count']
      y2 = df['Month']

      figure1 = Figure(figsize=(8,3), dpi=100)
      subplot1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
      subplot2 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
      bar1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, root)
      bar1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
      subplot1.plot(x, y1, color='green', linestyle='solid', linewidth = 2, marker='o', 
                    markerfacecolor='green', markersize=8, label='y1')
      subplot2.plot(x, y2, color='red', linestyle='solid', linewidth = 2, marker='o', 
                    markerfacecolor='red', markersize=8, label='y2')

def clear_charts():
      bar1.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()

browseButton_Excel1 = tk.Button(text='Load File...', command=getExcel1, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(400, 180, window=browseButton_Excel1)

button2 = tk.Button (root, text='Clear Chart', command=clear_charts, bg='green', font=('helvetica', 11, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(400, 220, window=button2)

button3 = tk.Button (root, text='Exit!', command=root.destroy, bg='green', font=('helvetica', 11, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(400, 260, window=button3)

root.mainloop()
```

The measure of x-axis should look like '2021-09-06 16:35:00', but it is only comes with '2021'.
Here is my excel file date:
[image]

And also please suggest me how to put legend, axis label and figure name. Please help me out for this problem.

Comment: Upload your excel/Data as text it is hard to reproduce an example from image I tried to reproduce your tbale pandas kicking me a error saying invalid date formats

Comment: Day Time Count Month
6-9-21 16:35:00 10 9
2-1-00 16:37:00 20 6
3-1-00 16:38:00 30 4
4-1-00 16:39:00 40 5

Comment: Check solution @Sanghamitra Lahiri

Comment: @Bhargav TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.time") to str This error is coming

Comment: updated check know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's issue in `lambda`  functon. Simply concat with plus operator instead

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Data Analyser')
label1.config(font=('Arial', 20))
canvas1.create_window(400, 50, window=label1)


def getExcel1 ():
      global df

      import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
      df = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
      df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])

      
      daytime=df['Day'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Time'].astype(str)
      
      
      global bar1
      x = daytime
      y1 = df['Count']
      y2 = df['Month']

      figure1 = Figure(figsize=(8,3), dpi=100)
      subplot1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
      subplot2 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
      bar1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, root)
      bar1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
      subplot1.plot(x, y1, color='green', linestyle='solid', linewidth = 2, marker='o', 
                    markerfacecolor='green', markersize=8, label='y1')
      subplot2.plot(x, y2, color='red', linestyle='solid', linewidth = 2, marker='o', 
                    markerfacecolor='red', markersize=8, label='y2')

def clear_charts():
      bar1.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()

browseButton_Excel1 = tk.Button(text='Load File...', command=getExcel1, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(400, 180, window=browseButton_Excel1)

button2 = tk.Button (root, text='Clear Chart', command=clear_charts, bg='green', font=('helvetica', 11, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(400, 220, window=button2)

button3 = tk.Button (root, text='Exit!', command=root.destroy, bg='green', font=('helvetica', 11, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(400, 260, window=button3)

root.mainloop()
```

Gives #

[image]

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.time") to str Error is coming.